# Using MSBUILD on a Framework461 solution that references a NetStandard20 assembly

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, .net-core, .net-standard

I'm not even sure if what I'm trying to do is possible...

Sample code: [here](https://github.com/antonfelich/netstandard_test)

Basically, I've built a netstandard20 class library which according to the .NET implementation support list should be compatible with a framework461 project (providing you have the .NET Core 2.0 SDK).

[image]

I can build the netstandard20 class library no worries and get the DLL back (it's included in the sample code).

This is where the problem starts, when attempting to run `msbuild .\netstandard_test.sln` to build the framework461 project I get a whole bunch of (what I believe to be misleading) errors about 'netstandard' not being referenced (which it is).

[image]

However, if I run `dotnet build` (or build from VS2017) everything works as expected.

I've tried importing various versions of NetStandard, NetStandard.Library and NetStandard.Library.Framework, as well as referencing Microsoft.DotNet.BuildTools but that didn't appear to help.

Is there any way to build this using msbuild? We have a monolithic build and deployment process and I'd rather not have to change it if it can be avoided. Who knows what else would go wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build with .NET Core or .NET Standard you need to use the [`dotnet msbuild` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-msbuild) from the .NET Core SDK rather than just plain `msbuild`.

```
dotnet msbuild .\netstandard_test.sln /p:Configuration=Release
```

This will also work with .NET Framework 4.6.1 (and older versions).

Do note that Microsoft has provided [install scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script) to make installing the .NET Core SDK painless on continuous integration servers.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself right. I can build the netstandard20 class library fine and have produced a DLL as expected.

The problem is my framework461 project referencing said DLL won't build with `msbuild`.

Comment: Right - which is why you need to build with `dotnet msbuild`. Older versions of `msbuild` don't recognize .NET Standard libraries that are referenced. The reason why the documentation says you need to have `.NET Core SDK 2.0` installed is because that is the only version of MSBuild it works with.

Comment: Well, that sucks :( Looks like I get to mess with our build pipeline. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: there's no need to use `dotnet msbuild` as long as VS 2017 has all the necessary workloads installed

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a recent 15.* version (currently 15.5.*) of MSBuild and make sure that the "Cross platform development" workload is installed in visual studio. This adds the required components to locate the .NET Core SDK, which contains MSBuild SDKs like `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` or `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` used by .NET Standard and .NET Core projects.

You can then use `msbuild` from the developer command prompt to build these projects. I suggest adding `/restore` (msbuild >= 15.5.*) to make sure that a NuGet restore happened for sdk-based projects.

Since VS 2017 does not install a "global" version of MSBuild, be sure to use the version of MSBuild installed in the VS 2017 folders (check with `msbuild /version` or `where msbuild`).

`dotnet msbuild` has limitations when you use .resx files containing file references or non-string properties. Also, it does not support COM references or building strong named assemblies. If you need any of these features, use `msbuild` (VS 2017) over `dotnet msbuild` (.NET Core CLI)